# SQL - How to split results into buckets that have an approximately equal sum of values. Non normal distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a dataset like:

| Id | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000 |
| 2 | 9500 |
| 3 | 5000 |
| 4 | 4500 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| **Total** | 29027 |

how can I query it to get split the items in N buckets so that the sum(count) for each bucket is roughly equivalent?

If I am calculating it by hand and assuming = 3, then I might end up with something like:

| Bucket | Ids | Sum(Count) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2, 5, 8, 9 | 9513 |
| 3 | 3, 4, 6, 7, 10 | 9514 |

It kind of feels like SQL is not going to cut it and I should look to another language or excel

Comment: http://ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/096.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you *could* do this with SQL, but you'd need to define what algorithm you want, at the very least. There are many different approaches to this, as the paper linked above alludes to. Without that, this is far too broad

Comment: @shawnt00 - Thanks, I did not know the problem I was trying to solve is called multi-way number partitioning .That piece of knowledge opened up a ton of relevant google results

Answer (score 0):

This isn't entirely a one sql statement function, but you could turn this around into a UDF pretty quickly.

First I start with a variable that defines the number of buckets and the resulting table:

```
DECLARE @resultsTable table ( Bucket int, Summation int)
declare @bucketCount int
set @bucketCount = 3
declare @buckCtr int
set @buckCtr = 1
WHILE @buckCtr <= @bucketCount BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @resultsTable select @buckCtr, 0
  set @buckCtr += 1
END
select @bucketCount = count(Bucket) from @resultsTable
```

The following temp table represents the values you provided above

```
declare @tempTable table (Id int,[Count] int)
insert into @tempTable select 1, 10000
insert into @tempTable select 2, 9500
insert into @tempTable select 3, 5000
insert into @tempTable select 4, 4500
insert into @tempTable select 5, 10
insert into @tempTable select 6, 8
insert into @tempTable select 7, 5
insert into @tempTable select 8, 2
insert into @tempTable select 9, 1
insert into @tempTable select 10, 1
```

The first pass is to fill the top level buckets:

```
set @buckCtr = 1
WHILE @buckCtr <= @bucketCount BEGIN
    UPDATE @resultsTable SET Summation = (SELECT TOP 1 [Count] FROM @tempTable ORDER BY Count DESC) where bUCKET = @buckCtr
    DELETE from @tempTable WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @tempTable ORDER BY COUNT DESC)
  set @buckCtr += 1
END
```

Here I just proof that the top values got pulled and the remaining dataset contains the other entries.

```
select * from @resultsTable
select * from @tempTable
```

The following is the crux of the data layout.  The jist is that we keep track of the inputted data table's row count as we remove the rows, take the top value and place it in a bucket.  After the placement into the bucket occurs, the bucket indexes are reset based on the summation value to prevent the bottom bucket from consuming too much.  As the values are placed, they are removed from the inputted data set:

```
declare @rowCount int
select @rowcount = count(id) from @tempTable
DECLARE @ReverseBucketIndex int
SET @ReverseBucketIndex = @bucketCount

while @rowCount > 0 BEGIN
    declare @nextVal int
    set @nextVal = (select top 1 [Count] from @tempTable order by [count] desc)

    while @ReverseBucketIndex > 0 begin
        DECLARE @CurrentVal int, @PriorVal int
        
        SELECT @CurrentVal = Summation FROM @resultsTable WHERE Bucket = @ReverseBucketIndex
        select @PriorVal = Summation FROM @resultsTable WHERE Bucket = @ReverseBucketIndex - 1
        
        if @nextVal + @CurrentVal <= @PriorVal OR @CurrentVal = @PriorVal or @PriorVal = null BEGIN
          UPDATE @resultsTable SET Summation = Summation + @nextVal where bucket = @ReverseBucketIndex
          SET @ReverseBucketIndex = 0
          BREAK
        END 
        SET @ReverseBucketIndex -= 1
    end

    update @resultsTable set Bucket = tt.Bucket from @resultsTable rt INNER JOIN (select bucket, summation, row_number() over (order by summation desc) as [NewNumber] from @resultsTable) tt on rt.Bucket = tt.NewNumber
    SET @ReverseBucketIndex = @bucketCount
    delete top(1) from @tempTable
    select @rowcount = count(id) from @tempTable
    END
    
    
    SELECT * FROM @resultsTable order by bucket
```

With the bucket indexing from above, I get

```
1, 10000
2, 9515
3, 9512
```

Without the bucket reindexing (the last update statement in the loop), I get

```
1, 10000
2, 9513
3, 9514
```

With five buckets, I get

```
1, 10000
2, 9500
3, 5000
4, 4500
5,27
```

Which seems to follow the logic of how you wanted the data to lay out.

If you wanted to see how the results fair with a much larger dataset, here I'm generating 10000 random numbers and then look at the distributions:

```
declare @randomCtr int
set @randomCtr = 10000

while @randomCtr >0 BEGIN
  insert into @tempTable select @randomctr, FLOOR(RAND()*100000-10+1)
    SET @randomCtr -= 1
END
```

When I visually inspect the results, no matter the bucket size, they all seem relative in value.